# Rename hg branch and transplant selective changes

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am working on BRANCH_A. I want to move the last 50 commits on this branch to a new branch BRANCH_B and revert BRANCH_A to the previous commit before these. What is the best method to achieve the same? Is it a good way?

Comment: "revert to the previous commit before these" **require** translation into the proper (relevant and meaningful) wording

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you just want BRANCH_A to be at the state of "HEAD - 50 commits" and you do not care if those commits appear in the history, then here is a simple solution:

For having all the commits on a new branch BRANCH_B you can simply create this branch while at the HEAD of BRANCH_A:

```
$ hg branch BRANCH_B
```

For restoring a previous state on BRANCH_A you can switch back to the HEAD of BRANCH_A, and commit a new changeset that will undo all the ones you do not want, this is done with hg backout:

```
$ hg update BRANCH_A
$ hg log -r 'branch(BRANCH_A) and head()~50 and not merge()'
$ hg backout -r 'branch(BRANCH_A) and head()~50 and not merge()'
$ hg commit -m"removed from .. to .."
```

You might have conflicts if changes happen in similar zones.

If you do want to rewrite history, you can either use the rebase or convert extensions to change names, remove commits etc. It all depends if you are working only locally or if you need to push to a server which is used by other people as well (in which case it is not advised to rewrite history).

Answer (score 0):

Without editing history, simply:

1. Close the tip of BRANCH_A.
2. Create a named BRANCH_B off the closed tip of BRANCH_A.
3. Check in new commits to BRANCH_A starting from the node before the 50 commits.

[image: TortoiseHg image of the idea, with one commit representing the "50"]